# android left drawer list icon not showing

Tags: android, android-drawer

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/portal"
            android:icon="@drawable/memu_icon_home_off"
            android:title="@string/menu_home"
            />
    </group>    <!-- show -->

        <item android:title="@string/menu_category"
            android:icon="@drawable/memu_icon_category_on"
            myapp:showAsAction="always">   <!-- not showing! -->
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct001"
                android:title="@string/title_ct001" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct002"
                android:title="@string/title_ct002" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct003"
                android:title="@string/title_ct003" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct004"
                android:title="@string/title_ct004" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct005"
                android:title="@string/title_ct005" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct006"
                android:title="@string/title_ct006" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/ct007"
                android:title="@string/title_ct007" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/appinfo"
            android:icon="@drawable/memu_icon_set_off"
            android:title="@string/appinfo"
            />
    </group>   <!-- show -->

</menu>
```

I want to print left `listlayout` like it

```
(icon1) home

(icon2) category

  category value.....

  category value.....

  category value.....

  category value.....

  category value.....

(icon3) app inf

'menu_icon_category_on'(icon2)
```

this item's icon not showing (groups icon can see)

How can I show it?

Comment: You have to place every **<item tag** under **<menu tag**

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: What I've understood till now is that you want icons only in the header not in the subitems. Right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/portal"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="Home" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grpidCategory">
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="menu_category"
            myapp:showAsAction="always" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grpidCatItems">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct001"
            android:title="title_ct001" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct002"
            android:title="title_ct002" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct003"
            android:title="title_ct003" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct004"
            android:title="title_ct004" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct005"
            android:title="title_ct005" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct006"
            android:title="title_ct006" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ct007"
            android:title="title_ct007" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grpid2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/appinfo"
            android:icon="@drawable/feedback"
            android:title="appinfo" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

You can add images in the subitems of Category if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this once

  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:icon="@drawable/a"
        android:title="@string/a"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:icon="@drawable/b"
        android:title="@string/b"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:title="@string/c"
        android:icon="@drawable/c"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>


    <!-- More -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_overflow"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="More">
        <menu>

            <item android:id="@+id/d"
                android:icon="@drawable/s"
                android:title="@string/d"
                app:showAsAction="never" />

            <item android:id="@+id/e"
                android:title="@string/e"
                app:showAsAction="never" />


            <item android:id="@+id/f"
                android:icon="@drawable/f"
                android:title="@string/f"
                app:showAsAction="never" />

        </menu>
    </item>
    </menu>
```